# Was Gaea more evil than her daughter, Rhea?

Tags: greek, myth-identification

I am writing a short poem about Greek deities and I am debating over Gaea or Rhea as evil goddesses. I have tried looking over multiple sources and answered questions about Gaea, the Mother Earth, in being evil in any way.

In some places it is said that Rhea was more evil than Gaea, as she supported Kronus, however, she did turn against him and helped Zeus overthrow Kronus at the end.

I can say that in a way Rhea was the start of evil in the world as she was the one who married Kronus, and let him engulf her children.

**Who was more evil** (even in the slightest sense), Gaea or Rhea?

Comment: Define evil. Does the word even apply to anything a god does?

Comment: @RedSonja, I think "evil" is simply used here as the opposite of "good".  "Bad" would have perhaps been a better choice.  I tend to think of "evil" as appearing to be good but ultimately being bad.

Comment: @RedSonja, in the last sentence I used the phrase 'even in the slightest sense'. Even though each God had good intents I meant to ask if Gaea or Rhea were as bad as Kronos was (or less), which could be determined by their actions only, not their intentions. Thus, by 'evil' I merely meant bad in a way, for example, Kronus was, however it is not necessary to be at the exact extent as him.

Comment: Then define "good". Who decides what good is? Or bad? Maybe you need a supreme court of boss gods to decide. But then, who chooses members of that court?

Comment: @RedSonja, if a God fulfills its' purpose of being then it will be good. Eg. keeping check on normal beings. However, my question over here is related to any evil act or treachery among the Gods, not upon humans. Relating to your questions the Olympians destroyed Kronus to restore balance against the evils he committed, but as Zeus himself lead the revenge he was regarded as highest among the 12 Olympians. Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: Are the myths even consistent enough to make a judgment?

Comment: @Mary I would just debate over whatever myths anyone has collected. After all they are nothing but myths.

Comment: The ancient Greeks did not believe that any of their gods, Cronus included, were "evil." That's a Christian invention. They were operating on a might-is-right model for the gods.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your perspective. While yes, Rhea was Kronos's wife, it is worth pointing out that Gaea is the mother of the Titans, so one must consider that when thinking about who is eviler. Besides, there are a multitude of myths where Rhea is shown doing good things, for example fixing Dionysus's brain after Hera made him go crazy. Plus, Gaea did create the Giants, who attack Mount Olympus and either force the gods to flee or require them to call upon the aid of mortal heroes. If it were up to me, I would say that Gaea is the more "evil" goddess, as there are more myths where she is acting as an antagonist.

Answer (score 2):

Their husbands ate the kids and you think Gaia and Rhea are evil?  Not too chauvinistic.

To preneolithic Greeks Gaia and Rhea represented the thin line between civilization and barbarism.  In the patriarchal societies of the neolithic they did get tramp stamped pretty badly and for that cycle I refer to the first answer here.  But at least in the Theogony, they weren't demons, they were the primal females.

That said, Gaia, like any mother in law, was into everbody's business and Rhea was notoriously vain about her beauty.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I would suggest not to answer the question with a question, however, you are most welcome to do so in the comment sectiont. I am aware that there are worse deities in Greek mythology compared to Gaea and Rhea, but I have to choose between these two only.

Comment: So noted, thank you.